# login example for iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Can anyone get me a login page example for iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer - Create a view with 2 labels (lblLogin & lblPassword) and 2 text fields (txtLogin & txtPassword) then generate the necessary source

long answer - post what you have tried so far

Comment: I want to find how to trap the button's click gesture. how to do that ?

Comment: using IB and XCode, link the button press(es) to actions.  If that doesn't make sense, SO will not help you (you'll need to learn more about the platform before going any further)